# adding a button to a c# mvc project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I've created a simple .NET MVC project, following the walkthrougth on MSDN.com.

I'm confused about how I'd go about adding a button to the page, so that I can map an action to it.

I've tried searching the web for this, but haven't found what I'm looking for.

Does anyone know of any resources that could help me?

**EDIT**

The JS for the search bar is below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
    $('#search').MyApp('init');
    $('#search').bind('selectItem', function (event, target) {
        alert($(target).attr('data'));
    });

    //        $.getJSON("http://localhost", {},
    //                function (x) {
    //                    //                    var x = [1, 2, 3];
    //                    alert("test");
    //                });

    //        alert('here')
});
</script>
```

Wha do I need to do to add a search button you can click?

Comment: Step 1) Post code.  Step 2) Explain the problem you are having in detail. Step 3) Vote up and accept and answer if it helps you.

Comment: add an <input type='button'> in the view, it's still ASP.NET, but forget drag & drop controls on the view, you have to actually code the view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can it like this..

in your razor view

```
@using(Html.Beginform("action", "controller")){
//insert some form
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />}
```

and in your controller you must define a action with that actionname that makes the logic

Answer (score 1):

You can find a lot of helpful tutorials and videos on the [ASP.NET web site](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot map an action directly to a button.
You can however determine in the controller which button made a submit call.

2 other options:

1. Write some javascript to perform the method call for you
2. Make a URL and style it as  a button (by far the easiest method if you don't need to post data)